# MySQL: Update row when Unique Index Collides

Tags: mysql

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `IDM_USER_MEASURE` (
  `USER_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `MEASURE_ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `MEASURE_DATE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `MEASURE_STATUS` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

And i added a unique index:

```
ALTER TABLE `IDM_USER_MEASURE`
    ADD UNIQUE KEY unique_measure (`USER_ID`, `MEASURE_ID`, `MEASURE_DATE`);
```

I now do the following:

```
INSERT INTO `IDM_USER_MEASURE`(`USER_ID`, `MEASURE_ID`, `MEASURE_DATE`, `MEASURE_STATUS`) VALUES(1, 1, "bla", "status one");
INSERT INTO `IDM_USER_MEASURE`(`USER_ID`, `MEASURE_ID`, `MEASURE_DATE`, `MEASURE_STATUS`) VALUES(1, 1, "bla", "status updated");
```

This does not work because of the unique index but i want the old row to be updated so that "status one" becomes "status updated".

How can i update my row automatically when unique index collides?

Answer (score 2):

MySQL offers the [REPLACE INTO](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html) statement, which will update existing rows if constraints are violated.

> `REPLACE` works exactly like `INSERT`, except that if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `UNIQUE` index, the old row is deleted before the new row is inserted.

```
REPLACE INTO `IDM_USER_MEASURE`(`USER_ID`, `MEASURE_ID`, `MEASURE_DATE`, `MEASURE_STATUS`) VALUES(1, 1, "bla", "status updated");
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b0f6b/1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Replace into is crushing the index isnt it? I guess i found a good solution: `INSERT INTO `IDM_USER_MEASURE`(`USER_ID`, `MEASURE_ID`, `MEASURE_DATE`, `MEASURE_STATUS`) VALUES(1, 1, "bla", "status updated") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE MEASURE_STATUS = VALUES(MEASURE_STATUS);`

Comment: Yes, it's delete then insert. Not great if you have a huge dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Manually only.

The closest you could automating such a thing would be a trigger; but those do not permit you to change data in the table the operate on (other than the row being triggered... similar to `INSERT`'s optional `ON DUPLICATE KEY` clause)

Alternately, you could remove the stringent uniqueness constraint and instead have an `EVENT` that does this on regular intervals. Of course, the drawback with this is that during each interval, non-unique sets of values can accumulate.

Another option would be to restrict INSERTs to the table from normal users and instead create a stored procedure (defined with the appropriate permissions) to handle those inserts, to run an UPDATE before the INSERT.

*Edit: Oh, I see, question wanted to update existing row instead of insert, as opposed to updating existing row so the insert could create a new row without uniqueness violation.*